# Unable to group chat on Facebook with Empathy?

Tags: empathy

I can't take part in a Facebook group chat with Empathy.

Do you know if there is a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a problem of empathy, facebook does not provide API for group chat

Comment: Has there been any progress on this?

Comment: Not as of right now. It can only be implemented if Facebook releases a public API for programs like Empathy to support group chat. As far as I know, Facebook has currently no plans to do so.